# Authenticated request to passport local pending

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, authentication, passport-local

I am developing an authentication application using Node, MongDB, Passport, Express and React. I am trying to fix this issue 2 days, but still get stuck. The error is after data sending to server, server does not process that request. Here is my configuration:

**Passport Local configuration**

```
  const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  passport.use({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  }, new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    /*Match username or not*/
    User.findOne({ email: username }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
        return done(err)
      }
      /* user not found */
      if (!user) {
        console.log(`User not matched!`)
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'That email is not registered'
        })
      }
      /*Match password*/
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user)
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Password incorrect'
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }))
```

**Authentication Router**

```
router.post('/auth/local/login', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Login info: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`)
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: false
  })
})
```

**Client Side**

```
  formData.append('username', username)
  formData.append('password', password)
  const data = new URLSearchParams(formData)
  fetch('/auth/local/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(json)}`)
      handleAuthenticated(json)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

**Log at Server side**

```
Server started successfully at 3001!
Database connected successfully!
Login info: {"username":"newemail@yahoo.com","password":"123456"}
```

**Inspect by Browser**

[image]

Comment: Any console error? For both FE and BE. Maybe some CORS headers problem?

Comment: No errors found. In my case request from client was sent successfully to the server, but the server did not process anything. So i think the issue does not come from CORS. After user submit login button, status is pending and 1 or 2 minutes it is changed to failed.

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue fixed. Basically we just handle the authentication inside the callback function of passport.authenticate('local') like below:

```
router.post('/auth/local/login', (req, res, next) => {
   passport.authenticate('local', {
     session: false
    }, (err, user, info) => {
      if(err || !user) return res.status(401).json({
         auth: false,
         msg: "Authentication failed",
         token: null
      }) 
      req.login(user, {session: false}, err => {
         if(err) res.send(err)
      })
      const token = jwt.sign(user.id, key.tokenSecret)
      return res.status(200).json({
        auth: true,
        msg: "Login successfully",
        token: token
      })
   })(req, res)
})
```

** Session is set to false, cause we don't want to store user in session.

And now it works perfectly. At client side, depends on the response we receive from the server, we redirect user to right page. I have tested both: success and failed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the right method signature of `passport.use`. The right one is this one:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
```

and not this:

```
passport.use({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  }, new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
  ...
}}
```

Comment: Also check here: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Comment: Refer to the documentation from Passport http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/ i think i am doing a right configuration. Because by default Passport take two parameters "username" and "password". If you see the requested data that i logged from server side above, it has two fields username and password as well. I have same idea with you, that the error might be come from my passport's configuration, but everything seems to be fine.